# export typescript classes and interfaces from a single file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, module

I want to be able to export some of my classes/interfaces/enums from other files in a single file. This is how I have done it in javascript:

```
module.exports = {
    Something = require("./src/something").default,
    SomethingElse = require("./src/something-else").default
}
```

I've noticed that I do not get intellisense from my webstorm (jetbrains) editor, and I'm pretty sure that there is an easier way to implement this in typescript. I've heard and read about modules but I still don't get what they purpose is, most likely they could help me here.

I want to be able to use this style on the library consumer:

```
import { Something, SomethingElse } from "my-ts-library";
...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flow my example:

`Something.ts`

```
export default (a: number, b: number): number => {
  return a + b;
};
```

`SomethingElse.ts`

```
export default (a: number, b: number): number => {
  return a - b;
};
```

`my-ts-library.ts`

```
import add from './src/Something.ts';
import sub from './src/SomethingElse.ts';
export {
  add,
  sub,
};
```

using your lib

```
import { add, sub } from "my-ts-library";
...
```